# Ajax.RouteLink gives a 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-ajax, actionmethod

I have this link

```
@Ajax.RouteLink("Bid", RouteNames.Ajax.BidOnLot,
            new
            {
                lotId = Model.Lot.Id,
                bidAmount = Model.NextBidAmountForUser
            },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"
            })
```

and this action method

```
[AjaxOnly, HttpPost]
        [Route("ajax/bid-on-lot/{lotId}/{bidAmount}", Name = RouteNames.Ajax.BidOnLot)]
        [Authorize]
        public JsonResult Bid(string lotId, decimal bidAmount)
```

`RouteNames.Ajax.BidOnLot` is set to `"BidOnLot"`

But for some reason when I click on the link, I get a 404 with this message.

```
404 Not Found - http://localhost:12472/ajax/bid-on-lot/lot-901/210.0
```

When I have only the LotId parameter everything works normally but adding an additional parameter makes it all fail.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else struggles with this in the future let me tell you what the issue was.  Passing a decimal parameter was the issue.  Passing an int, double or string is fine but when I made it a decimal it failed.